# Loading images gracefully

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

How can I load the images more gracefully with this slideshow?

http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/CkuKe/11/

Larger images take longer to load, obviously and it looks messy when they load on top of each other like that.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/SxHNn/

wait for an image load THEN start the interval. @Starx is right though, particularly because some browsers do not fire load events on cached images. So without waitforimages the interval will not start after a page refresh in some browsers. Use the fiddle I posted but use `.waitForImages` from the pluggin instead of jQuery's `.load`

Alternatively because you are not using background-images you could you Paul Irish's more concise solution: https://gist.github.com/268257

Answer (score 2):

For your case, there is a plugin called [waitforimages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages), which is perfect.

Just run the function when all the images have been loaded.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in this direction. The implementation is simple enough in terms of the code but I'm not having any success wherever I add it to the existing code.

Comment: Try to post a question related to that. I will take a look